# Rails query timestamp between two hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a problem in Ruby on Rails, where I need to allow a user to set a two time columns, and then query all instances of that model that have the current time within the hours of the two timestamps. Days do not matter, just within the times specified be the start and end timestamps.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Does the user select two timestamps?

Comment: Please tell us what database you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work (assuming MySQL):

```
Model.where("TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '09:00:00'")
```

You can convert a `Time` instance to this format with:

```
Time.now.strftime("%T") #=> "23:02:25"
```

If the start time is larger than the end time you could reverse the logic, so instead of:

```
Model.where("TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '01:59:59'")
```

You could use:

```
Model.where("TIME(created_at) NOT BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '22:59:59'")
```

Comment: Thats good, but does it work across dates? For example what if the query was `TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '21:00:00 AND 03:00:00'`

Comment: Don't know, does it? :-)

Comment: Now is there some kind of ternary operator or IF/ELSE clause I can use to determine which query to use based on the two timestamps?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like

`Model.where("starts_at >= ? AND ends_at =< ?", Time.current, Time.current)`

Alternatively, you can use [placeholder conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#placeholder-conditions) to make the query more concise.

`Client.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",
  {start_date: params[:start_date], end_date: params[:end_date]})`

Comment: The problem is that it can't be date specific, but it still needs to work if the start and end date cross the date-line

Answer (score 0):

How you solve this problem will depend on what database you're using b/c as far as I'm aware there aren't any `ActiveRecord` helpers for this type of operation. But there are date functions that should help you figure this out

[Postgres Date functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html)

[Mysql Date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

So for example, in Postgres you might try

```
extract(hour from timestamp 'a') BETWEEN (extract(hour from timestamp  'b') AND extract(hour from timestamp 'c'))
```