# Rails query timestamp between two hours with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to get records from hours + minutes interval not connected with date in postgresql. For example all records from last month which were created between 15:15 and 18:30.

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576109/rails-query-timestamp-between-two-hours) but it does not work in postgresql.

For only hours I tried

```
Review.where("extract('hour' from created_at) > 15 AND extract('hour' from created_at) < 18")

SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE (extract('hour' from created_at) > 15 AND extract('hour' from created_at) < 18)
```

however I have no idea how to deal with the minutes.

Comment: have you tried there postgre version of solution?

Comment: Yep, it contains extract similar to what I writed above.

Comment: where is between keyword?

Comment: This solution takes only hours into consideration and I need minutes also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast `created_at` to a `time` (which doesn't include the date) and then use `BETWEEN`.

```
#= select * from times;
          t
---------------------
 2016-01-01 12:00:00
 2016-02-02 13:00:00
 2016-03-03 14:00:00
 2016-04-04 15:00:00
(4 rows)
```

```
#= select * from times where t::time between '12:30:00' AND '14:30:00';
          t
---------------------
 2016-02-02 13:00:00
 2016-03-03 14:00:00
(2 rows)
```

Coming through Rails, that would be:

```
Review.where("created_at::time BETWEEN '12:30:00' AND '14:30:00'")
```